# How do I update Minecraft 1.8.8 to 1.9 on Mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

How do I install Minecraft 1.9 on Mac? I have tried uninstalling it, then reinstalling it, but it goes only up to 1.8.8. How do I get it to 1.9?  This is getting really frustrating too - I have a friend that has a Minecraft realm but I can't play on it because it says my client is out of date. -_-

Answer (score 2):

Click on "Edit Profile" in your Minecraft launcher. Go down to "Use Version" and set it to release 1.9. Click on "Save Profile".